# Xcode error in simulator

Tags: ios7, xcode5

When ever i try to run my app in 4inch 64bit mode this error comes up can someone please explain where i am going wrong. As soon as the simulator is switched back to the 3.5 inch it works fine all of my apps are there and they all run fine. i have tried googling this and just playing around with the software trying to find the problem and fix it but i can't seem to work it out. any help give would be amazing
[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

[image]

once the simulator has switched to the 4inch device the apps disappear.
Please can someone explain where i am going wrong

Comment: It's something in your code. You'll be able to see what the issue is if you do the following: Open the breakpoints menu on the left panel, click the + button to add a new breakpoint, select add exception breakpoint, right click on this new breakpoint and click edit, change the exception dropdown to Objective-C. Now your app should stop at a breakpoint wherever the error occurs and you can diagnose the problem from there.

Comment: Hi mike I haven't done any coding i have done it all from the console and dragged and dropped but i will try this now thanks for the help

Comment: Hi @mike I have tried this mike and it keeps switching to Xcode and showing me the same as whats in the last image on my post, i have added the break point as you suggested and i have edited it and i dose not seem to have changed anything theres nothing new in that area and when i click it just shows me that text in the last image. which is how its has been generated by Xcode